# Deploying v Releasing

Tags: web-applications, deployment, desktop-application

So there's this desktop application.

And I am wanting to inform it's users that a new version has been released.

Is it more correct to say that a new version of a desktop application has been 'released' or 'deployed' (as with a web app)?

Comment: Focus more on letting the user know what they need to do and what are the consequences.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deployed means that it's been shoved onto and works on a server or other machine (say an embedded chipset) somewhere. Released means that that machine and the application(s) on it has been made available to the public. So "release" would be the better term.

Comment: If something has been deployed, I can use it. If something has been released, I need to get it (and install it). If you're using something like ClickOnce to distribute your application which automatically checks for updates each time its run the line gets fuzzier

Comment: Fair enough but most lines are fuzzy in terms of where stuff is these days.

Comment: @Kevin yeah, so that's the thing, it is a ClickOnce application, but at the same time I guess they're still going to have to install something?

Comment: Yeah. You've released the software to your users by deploying the latest build to the ClickOnce Repository (UNC path etc.). They still have to click 'Accept' the next time they run the app to get the latest build.